# NginxとApacheの設定ファイルは何言語で書かれているのでしょうか？

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

NginxとApacheの設定ファイルは何言語で書かれているのでしょうか？
Nginxの設定ファイルを、$から始まる変数を使って書き換えている例を先日見かけました。
PerlかPHPですかね。

というのも、あるHTTPヘッダーの動的に(UNIX時間が動的な要素）変更したく、どうしようかなとぐぐっていたところ、設定ファイル内で条件文書いて設定していいる例があり参考にできないかなと思っています。
(他にこういう方法でもできるよ、というものがあると助かります

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の主旨は、設定ファイルの言語が知りたいのでしょうか。それとも動的にHTTPヘッダーを変更する方法が知りたいのでしょうか。後者であればより具体的な内容を掲載していただければ回答が着きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

設定ファイルに書かれているのはいわゆるプログラミング言語ではありません。
NginxやApacheはそれぞれ独自の構文がありそれによって書かれています。